# Incorporating a treatment into a classification scheme

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, predictive-models, feature-engineering

I have about 400 pieces of silver of different geometric dimensions. They were assigned to six groups and each group went through a series of stress tests, such as bending, pulling, putting in fire for a period of time, etc. The treatments that were given to the six groups were not the same, but fairly similar. The sizes of the six groups were not the same. The pieces either broke at some stage and that was recorded as a success or didn't, which was recorded as a failure. The time of each success was also recorded. The number of successes was about 80.

My goal is build a predictive model to determine if a piece of silver breaks based on its physical dimensions and the treatment it goes through.

I have been somewhat successful in building a model using the physical dimensions, but adding various aspects of the treatment (eg. total time spent in fire) didn't improve the performance at all. I have even tried to build features (eg.total stress on the metal in various directions, total strain on the metal, etc.)  based on the physical dimensions and the treatment, for each individual piece, but even these didn't add any predictive performance.

How can I incorporate the treatment information in a way that adds to my predictive power? It is clear that the treatment is a factor in whether a piece breaks or not, and it should somehow show up somewhere.

N.B. I didn't have any control over the design of the treatment, and testing more samples with other treatments is not an option for me.

I'd very much appreciate any suggestions or comments.
Many thanks!

Comment: Hi there, what techniques/models have you used so far for analysing your data? Can you also show the variables you used in each model?

Comment: Hi Michelle, I've tried almost every classification scheme that I could get my hands on off the shelf, but Naive Bayes seems to work best. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the list of variables. Are you referring to those coming from the treatment? For the treatment variables, I've tried everything I could think of: number hours being bent, maximum heat, maximum pressure. Anything I could think of.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear more about anything you may have found using logistic regression, and whether regression diagnostics could shed any light on your problem.  This is a bit of a long shot, but perhaps incorporating nonlinear terms for one or more treatment predictors would help.

Comment: Hi rolando2. I got perhaps the poorest results from using logistic regression. I have no idea why. Regularized logistic regression did much better. I didn't use any nonlinear terms though.

Comment: When you say "it is clear the treatment is a factor", what is this based on? Would a human be able to come up with a rule for the success rate based on treatment?

Comment: Hi SheldonCooper. To compare two extremes, if the treatment is to pull the piece of silver with a very large force that exceeds the tolerance of every one of my 600 pieces, then every piece will eventually break, so the success rate is 100% in this case. On the other hand, if I do absolutely nothing to each piece, the success rate is 0%. In these simple cases we can say, by just looking at the treatments, what the success rates are going to be. However, if the treatment is very complicated, I'm not sure how a human can come up with a rule. I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Were these extremes present in the actual experiments? Were they present in a large enough fraction of cases to notice any increase in predictive power of your model? As an analogy, consider how ambient temperature influences human life. If the temeprature is an absolute zero a person would freeze, and if the temperature is 1000K, the person would burn. But if you only collected samples at temperatures between 60F and 80F, you won't see any of these effects. If you collected 400 samples and only two were at extreme temperatures, your prediction rate would improve by only 0.5%.

Comment: No, there wasn't that much variation in the actual experiments. My suspicion is that that is the reason I don't see much improvement in prediction by adding the treatments in the ways I've added them so far. I'm wondering if there is a way to magnify the differences between the various treatments though.

Comment: What seems most reasonable to me is computing the stress the treatment causes and using it as feature. E.g. sample was bent; you compute the max force and duration, then use 3 features: force, duration, and force times duration. You did that already and it didn't work. I suspect this is because there isn't enough variation in the experiments. But it may also be that you didn't try the right set of features. Unfortunately, there aren't many guidelines to design features. I can dream up a bunch of things (you probably can too), but it's a matter of trial and error to pick the right ones.

Comment: I would try to go at it differently. Do another round of experiments with just one treatment (e.g. bending) and with enough variation. Make it simple enough that you know there is a rule, and that you actually know what the rule is (e.g. bending force > X => success). You can then pick features you think are reasonable and try them on this new set. You will then be able to debug your algorithm and your features until you get something that works. You know what it should look like on this simple set. You can then use these features on the old set and see how well they work.

Comment: I wish I could do another round of experiments, but as I mentioned in the question, that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You might try some tree based models, such as [randomForest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html) or [GBM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/) in R.  Both models are good at picking up non-linear effects and interactions, and both also produce variable importance measures that will probably be useful in your analysis.

[GBM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/vignettes/gbm.pdf) in particular might be useful, as it fits each successive tree to the residuals of the model.  In this way, after the model captures the effects of geometric dimensions, it will explore how the various treatments might be used to explain the "leftover" (or residual) variance. On the other hand, random forests require very little tuning and are harder to screw up than GBM models.

I would make sure each treatment is its set of variables, e.g. total time in fire, min/mean/median/max/cumulative bending and pulling pressure, etc.  Particularly in GBM models, more variables are better, so be thorough!

How are you measuring how "good" your models are?  Are you cross-validating them?

Comment: Thank you Zach. I've tried random forests (though not in R), and it doesn't work that great. In fact, none of the tree-based methods have worked that great. I haven't tried GBM though. I'm not sure what you mean by "in GBM models, more variables are better". Does that mean that overfitting doesn't happen in GBM? I'm using 10 runs of 10-fold CV to validate my models. I'm using AUC and also partial AUC as my measure of performance. I don't really think a particular algorithm is the answer.

Comment: I think you should give GBM a shot.  GBMs will eventually overfit, depending on how many trees you use.  The GBM algorithm in R has built-in cross validation to tune the number of trees to prevent this.  Try using the `bernoulli` and `adaboost` distributions.  If no algorithm is working well, you need to re-examine your research question and see if there's any important variables you are missing.  Did you make sure your random forest was a classification, rather than a regression forest?

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a shot. But I think a more fundamental approach would be to somehow amplify small differences between the treatments so that one can use them more effectively in the classification scheme.

Comment: @user765195: Well, you could code the different treatments as a categorical variable (e.g. treatment 1 is 10 minutes in fire, treatment 2 is 20 minutes in fire, treatment 3 is 10 lbs of pulling pressure, etc.).  If there are significant differences among treatments, this would let your model pick them up.  However, if most of the failures can be explained by geometry rather than treatment, this is going to be very hard.  Could you post some sample data?

Comment: Hi Zach. The treatments are a lot more complicated than what you describe. They're combinations of actions performed for various lengths of time, and each treatment was the same for the a group, but different groups went through different treatments. The problem is that most of the failures can't be explained by geometry (some can). The goal is to add the treatment to the classification features somehow to make the classification more accurate.

Comment: @user765195 How many total treatments are we looking at?  Did any groups receive multiple treatments? Some example data would be really useful in answering this question.

Comment: Zach, here is an example.
Subject ID, Group, Length, Height, Width
1 , 3, 20in, 5in, 4in
2, 4, 18in, 4.5in, 3.7in
....
400, 1, 17in, 3.7in, 4.2in

and for treatments, the following, in the specified order
Group 1
1- Pulling by a force of 10lb, 5 minutes
2- Fire, 500 degrees, 1 hour

Comment: Zach, here is an example.
Subject ID, Group, Length, Height, Width//
1 , 3, 20in, 5in, 4in//
2, 4, 18in, 4.5in, 3.7in//
....//
400, 1, 17in, 3.7in, 4.2in//

/and for treatments, the following, in the specified order://
Group 1//
1- Pulling by a force of 300lb, 5 minutes
2- Fire, 500 degrees, 1 hour
3- Pressed by a force of 500lbs, 1 hour
etc. //

Group 2//
1 - Fire, 550 degrees, 45 minutes
2 - Pressed by a force of 540 lbs, 1 hour 15 minutes
3 - Pulling by a force of 380 lbs, 20 minutes,
etc. //
and you can imagine a similar pattern for the other groups.

Answer (score 1):

The functional form of the model is going to be very important here. In fact there might be interaction effects between the treatments (*sensitivity of breaking to bending might depend on whether it has been put through fire before*) and hence you need to use a non-linear functional form

So, instead of a form like: $$y=\beta_{fire}x_{fire}+ \beta_{bending}x_{bending} + .. $$ you might want to use a form: $$y=\beta_{bending-fire}x_{bending}x_{fire} + ..+\beta_{fire}x_{fire}+ \beta_{bending}x_{bending} + .. $$

You should start with this simple linear model and then move on to random forests since they will automatically create these interactions if they are important